# AngularJS scope variable not getting evaluated inside IE's conditional comment

Tags: angularjs

I have to use two iframes, one for IE8 and other for the rest of the browsers. I see that the angularjs scope variable (myUrl) is getting evaluated for the later iframe but not the first.

```
<div id="frameContainer" class="modal-body ios-scroll">
<!--[if IE 8]><iframe ng-src="{{myUrl}}?domain=http://localhost:9001/" class="signInIframe" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" height="620" width="600"></iframe> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 8)|!(IE)]><!--> <iframe ng-src="{{myUrl}}?domain=http://localhost:9001/" class="signInIframe" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe><!--<![endif]-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem may lie with Internet Explorer 8 and lower having problems with custom attributes. (e.g. ng-src)

Check out [this guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie) for more information.

> This document describes the Internet Explorer (IE) idiosyncrasies when dealing with custom HTML attributes and tags. **Read this document if you are planning on deploying your Angular application on IE v8.0 or earlier.** (emphasis mine)

To see if this is indeed the case, try doing what kmdsax suggested by changing `ng-src` to simply `src`. If that works, then your issue is most likely the custom attribute.

**NOTE: According to [the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSrc), if you don't use `ng-src` then your iframe won't resolve to the correct address. So make sure you read that IE compatibility guide to make IE8 and lower behave.**

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code in IE8 and it seems to be working fine. 
You dont really need to use `ng-src` here, you can also use `src`, and the `{{myUrl}}` variable will be evaluated the same. Try that, see if it makes a difference for you.